# How do I pass a comment to paypal's payment page?

Tags: paypal

I have a form that adds items to a cart. But I want to give them an option to ship the item to a store.

My form looks like this...

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />


<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="19.99" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="MyCoolTshirt" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="2" />


<input type="image" src="Checkout-Button.jpg" name="submit" alt="cart add" />
</form>
```

Can I add a code in there that will deliver the comment to me, indicating "Ship to store" so customer can pickup instead of shipping it to them?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [standard variables list](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) to see what all is available for you to use.  There are a few different things you could do.

You could save everything into your local database first, complete with all notes or anything you'd want to reference.  Then you can pass that "invoice ID" into the invoice parameter of your form, and you would always be able to relate back and pull that data from your own system.

You could also just use the "custom" parameter to pass anything you want up to 255 characters.

I'd browse through that list, though, as there could be lots of different things you decide you'd like to use.